# How to make a User signed_in from controller using devise and rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to make user signed_in from controller.
I used below code in controller

```
sign_in(:user, @user)
```

Using this I got current_user on same page.
But on second page I didn't get current_user.

Please help me!!

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sign_in @user, bypass: true
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Using this not getting current_user even on same page..:-(

Comment: No user is signed_in.